# How do I specify the types for the content (values) of a JS object (i.e. map)?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I want to specify that a Javascript Object, used as a map, contains only a certain type.

For example:

```
function doSomethingWithUrlQueryParams(queryObj: Object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use do it like this:

```
function doSomethingWithUrlQueryParams(queryObj: {[key: string]: string})
```